# Contributing to unmaintained reactor in Twisted or maintain separate implementation?

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming, open-source, twisted, kivy

## Future Edit

As of twisted 15.5.0 and kivy 1.9.1, the kivy implementation works on python3. I also use AMP, which is not yet in the release but was merged 2 months ago and will be in the next twisted release.

## Introduction

I'm developing an app using Kivy and plan to extend it using multi-processing and, more importantly Twisted. The app has a master component and a slave which should be controllable from various masters, including over a network (hence twisted).

Kivy has it's own twisted support code (in kivy/support.py called instal_twisted_reactor) which works in python2 but doesn't in python3 due to the unported status of the _threadedselect reactor.

I've hacked a port of twisted/internet/_threadedselect.py to python3 which is sufficient to run the kivy example code (one server GUI and one client GUI sending text). Normally I'd then go for a pull request upstream, but there's a few more factors in play:-

1. _threadedselect.py is, as best as I can tell, unmaintained in twisted, and in fact was last even mentioned on their mailing list back in 2006 (as a candidate for removal)
2. The twisted requirements for python3 porting include appropriate unit tests, and I don't have to knowledge (networking wise especially) to write appropriate unit tests for this reactor
3. I do not know whether any other project (besides kivy) even uses _threadedselect.py

## Main Question

Given the above, is it advisable to put in the effort to get _treadedselect.py patched upstream (and henced ported to python3)? Or would it be more efficient to maintain a separate implementation in my own project (or optionally contributed to kivy's project).

Disclaimer: I'm (obviously) not a maintainer for either project

## Non-essential details:

Kivy isn't the most popular UI base in python, hence it doesn't have a twisted maintained reactor (a la GTK, QT, TK etc.), but its the best fit for what I want to do. I've considered tornado etc. but that's really a matter for another question.

Also, the modifications needed are (so far) really minor. queue to Queue, zope interface decorators, except using as rather than comma, and using the function next rather than using a generator's next method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Twisted ecosystem.  I hope I can clear up your confusion so you can move forward.

First of all, Kivy is a very important Python library, and one we at the Twisted project definitely care about (I'm super happy to hear you're using them together!) so you are mistaken if you believe that Kivy doesn't have a reactor simply because it "isn't the most popular UI base in python"; the only reason it doesn't have a reactor in Twisted is that nobody contributed one.

There are a couple of possible ways forward, but they depend on some technical details you haven't covered in your question, and one SO answer is probably not enough to resolve the conflict; you will probably want to join the [Twisted mailing list](https://twistedmatrix.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/twisted-python) and discuss this there.

Regardless of the Python 3 port, `_threadedselect` is a private API, with no compatibility contract, and Kivy should not be using it.  So in order to move forward, this will need to change.  However, it is unlikely to be removed, as it is internally the basis of the wxpython reactor, which *is* a public API distributed with Twisted, and will eventually need to be ported to python 3 itself to complete the port.

The first way forward would be to improve `_threadedselect`'s test coverage and make it a public API again.  This strikes me as not necessarily the best move, because getting the thread interaction correct is very tricky and I would not want to encourage people - even people dealing with low-level enough implementation details to want to implement a reactor - to do it that way if any other options were available.  However, if `_threadedselect` had a valid use-case within Kivy, and an advocate willing to do some maintenance work, this is definitely plausible.

The second way forward would be to create a reactor based on an internal socket-monitoring API within Kivy.  Is there one?  Most of the UIs which Kivy is a wrapper over (CoreFoundation, X11, Windows) do have socket-monitoring of some kind built in.  Can Kivy tap into that, possibly?  This is less error-prone than threading, if you can manage it, but sometimes it's impossible; I don't see any directly exposed APIs in Kivy for this.  If you could develop such a thing it could be within Twisted or within Kivy depending on your preference.

I hope to hear from you in a more discussion-oriented forum soon :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Glyph, but on further investigation and coding I've concluded that twisted on python3 is just too much hassle for my project due to certain protocols (such as AMP) not being ported yet. At this point I'm leaning towards just using python2 (which is a shame, I like python3).

Comment: @NgOon-Ee - It may be too late for your project, but you should know that porting of Twisted continues, and is accelerating now that tools like `twistd` and `trial` have been ported.  With those tools, it's a lot easier to port other things.  So python 3 will be a viable option in the near future.

Comment: Actually @Glyph I AM using twisted (and just posted on the mailing list yesterday regarding that), it's only that I've decided that with that decision made I'll have to stick with python2 for the foreseeable future.

Comment: I am fighting this issue. Any workaround or solution?


  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/kivy/support.py", line 175, in install_twisted_reactor
    from twisted.internet import _threadedselect
ImportError: cannot import name '_threadedselect'

Comment: `_threadedselect` still hasn't been ported to python 3.  Either send a pull request to Twisted porting it, or switch to Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for following up. If I have time I'll take a crack at it next week.